# openstreetmap doesn't load map if zoom is >7 in android

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

OSM zoom just don't work for >7. In my project I donwnload datas from server. I use [volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)!, for download datas. So I had setted zoom on response(). I call method jsonArrayRequest()  in ovverided method

```
@Override
protected void addOverlays() {
    super.addOverlays();
    jsonArrayReuest("7701");
}
```

it works cool on sample, when this part of code was in addOverlays() method.

```
 mMyLocationOverlay = new ItemizedOverlayWithFocus<MapOverlayItem>(items,
     new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<MapOverlayItem>() {
             @Override
             public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index, final MapOverlayItem item) {
             // SingleTap
             return true;
            }
             @Override
             public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index, final MapOverlayItem item) {
            // LongPressed
             return false;
            }
     }, mResourceProxy);
```

but when I replace it to

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray response){
....
       mMyLocationOverlay.setFocusItemsOnTap(true);
       mMyLocationOverlay.setFocusedItem(0);
       mMapView.getOverlays().add(mMyLocationOverlay);
       mRotationGestureOverlay = new RotationGestureOverlay(activity.getApplicationContext(), mMapView);
       mRotationGestureOverlay.setEnabled(false);
       mMapView.getOverlays().add(mRotationGestureOverlay);
       /* MapTileProviderBasic */
       final MapTileProviderBasic tileProvider = new MapTileProviderBasic(activity.getApplicationContext());
       final ITileSource tileSource = new XYTileSource("FietsRegionaal", null, 3, 18, 256, ".png",new String[] { "http://overlay.openstreetmap.nl/openfietskaart-rcn/" });
       tileProvider.setTileSource(tileSource);
       final TilesOverlay tilesOverlay = new TilesOverlay(tileProvider, activity.getBaseContext());
       tilesOverlay.setLoadingBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
       mMapView.getOverlays().add(tilesOverlay);
       /* MiniMap */
       {
           MinimapOverlay miniMapOverlay = new MinimapOverlay(activity.getApplicationContext(),
           mMapView.getTileRequestCompleteHandler());
           mMapView.getOverlays().add(miniMapOverlay);
       }
       mMapView.getController().setZoom(16);
       IGeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(filialList.get(position).getPosition1(),filialList.get(position).getPosition2());
        //mMyLocationOverlay.getFocusedItem().getPoint();
       mMapView.getController().animateTo(geoPoint);
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your code doesn't set any zoom level at all, you mention "volley" in your question without explaining what it is, you didn't mention the tile provider you are using. Also your question ends abruptly.

Comment: Can you try a different tile provider? I guess the problem is just "FietsRegionaal" not providing the tiles you are requesting.

Comment: scai: in sample, it works without any tiles. I have added it,just because of, one proffessional said. But I think the problem is: I can't use volley sensibly, and initial some objects not right sequence.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you are trying to say. Can you rephrase your comment? Also I don't understand why you are using volley at all, osmdroid should work fine without it.

Comment: I use volley for download datas which I need to overlay on map. I understand now, that requests execute later and so objects cannot be initial. I can receive datas(which will be overlayed on map) from another class. I'm trying to do this right now. datas:names of Country,Town and so on. https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSQo58zSig5gKd-ayW3GY0NMczPf9DEI4-InvS_R2gXL-EVFqsk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72307/discussion-between-mdzht-and-scai).